# How can I figure out the I2C address of an OLED display?

Tags: i2c, raspberry-pi-pico

I've got an OLED display I am trying to write to from my Raspberry Pi Pico.

It's an SH1106 driver.

I can write fine when I set the I2C address to 0x3C, but behind the display there are two I2C address 0x78 and 0x7A - no 0x3C.

If I try either of the 0x78 or 0x7A numbers, I get a runtime error - device not found.

Comment: could you link to the datasheet of that SH1106?

Comment: What is 0x3c times 2?  0x78. Addresses can be confusing as some specify it as a 7bit number, others as an 8bit number. This is due to i2c having the r/w bit as bit0.

Comment: Not very intuitive - but thanks. if you move your comment to answer - i'll tag it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two de facto notations for I2C addresses, 7-bit address values with separate read/write bit which is not considered as part of the address value, and 8-bit address values where the read/write bit is included in the address value. Sometimes the 8-bit write address is used as the base value for the address, or it is said as a pair of read and write addresses.

0x3C in 7-bit notation is equal to 8-bit notation write and read address pair for 0x78 and 0x79.